# System sound playback is heard in microphone channel

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 19.10, microphone

When I do a recording of my microphone is also contains all system playback.

The sound settings dialog that displays the microphone input level live shows a full input level when I do the "Test" dialog on Output ("Front left/right"). The physical microphone is turned off/disconnected during this test.

I have tried the pavucontrol application and any "Monitor" stream in the Input tab is disabled and muted.

Other than that the mic and output works fine.

The headset is connected to the mobo with standard connectors.

*Update:*
Using `pactl` to load `module-echo-cancel` alleviates the problem a little bit, intermittent sounds still comes through.

Comment: If you still heard the system sound, then the used microphone may be the built in microphone, not the one in headset. You need to select the input device in setting > sound. Btw, I don't use 19.10 yet.

Comment: There is no built in microphone hardware. There is no physical sound playing during the test. The headset is set to zero, both the mic(on-off button) and headphones (volume control). I strongly suspect it is some kind of faulty mixing issue, but I have no idea how to troubleshoot that.

Comment: @da_kingpin "gaming headset" 2 individual 3.5 mm plugs. Desktop back panel. That is why I stated "The headset is connected to the mobo with standard connectors. "

Comment: @da_kingpin The mobo is about 3 years old. Switching to front connectors doesn't make any change. This is a new phenomenon with 19.10, it did not occur on 19.04.

Comment: also I've spent several hours in alsamixer with no progress on the diagnose.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was a compound issue, never properly diagnostisized. Resolved by buying a USB connected headset.

Answer (score 2):

Your sound is working, so this is probably not necessary. Check your sound hardware with

`hwinfo --sound` , `lshw -class multimedia` or `arecord --list-devices`

Make sure it matches what your MB vendor specs show. To get motherboard info

`sudo lshw -class bus | grep -A 6 -i 'motherboard'`

Make sure you have all the right modules and codecs loaded for your sound chip. You'll have to figure out those details about your chip and necessary modules

---

The `hdajackretask` tool in the "alsa-tools-gui" package will allow you to reconfigure audio jacks.

Certain chips don't seem to get reverse engineered properly upstream. Outputs and inputs may be pinned wrong. Some experimenting will be necessary. If a working configuration can be found, a patch to install a boot override could be used. I had issues with the Reaktek Azalia chip. That was the only way I found to get it working correctly. Pain in the A@#. But, this is free software with many volunteer contributors.

In some cases reinstalling alsa and pulseaudio can fix issues.

`sudo apt purge alsa-base pulseaudio`

-- take note of all uninstalled packages in case you need to manually reinstall some.

`sudo apt install alsa-base pulseaudio`

I Hope some of this helps lead you to a solution.

Comment: Sampling rate. There is a [pulseaudio/troubleshooting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Determine_sampling_rate_of_the_sound_card_(2/5)) page at Arch Wiki that mentioned the sampling rate causing recording artifacts that may relate to your issues.

Comment: Your reasonable suggestions unfortunately left me with an even more unreliable sound system. The Test-> "Front left/ Front right" no longer produces any sound at all.   I'm thinking there are two unknowns that interplay in a very unpredictable manner. The physical headset and the pulse module(s).

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and the `module-echo-cancel` temporary fix solves the issue completely for me. Since it took some time to have it properly working for me, I thought it would be nice to write it down here.

Append the following snippet in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

```
.ifexists module-echo-cancel.so
load-module module-echo-cancel aec_method=webrtc source_name=echocancel sink_name=echocancel1
set-default-source echocancel
set-default-sink echocancel1
.endif
```

and then restart the pulseaudo service (or reboot the machine):

```
pulseaudio -k
```

What it does:

> if your system PulseAudio is compiled with the echo / noise cancellation module, load this module, use webrtc as the echo cancellation method (it should be better than the default speex), specify a source and sink names, then set that source and sink as default.

Solution found on https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/09/how-to-enable-echo-noise-cancellation.html